# dynamic url path from current file in changing directories with php

Tags: php, dynamic, include, absolute, directory-structure

I need to include the same file (navigation.php) from differing directories and file path structures.
for instance i need to dynamically change the file depth eg:

```
include '../../../navigation.php';
```

and

```
include '../../../../../navigation.php';
```

need to be the same file (navigation.php).

furthermore i need to store the absolute path to (navigation.php)'s css and javascript files  in a variable that would be the same throughout all directories of my website as mentioned before.
for example in the cases where the following are true:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/main.css">
```

both directory paths would need to be referenced by one variable like this

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $rootpath; ?>/css/main.css">
```

I have tried to use `<?php echo " ".realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])."/path/to/root/"`

however this does not seem to work as i end up getting a path that looks like this

> C:\before\root/path/to/root.

What would be the most effective way of making a standard dynamic variable that would indicate the path relative to the current folder or how could I fix the current problem I am having with absolute paths?

Answer (score 0):

i try to use the basename function ? 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php ?